# Remotely access a Raspberry PI

Tags: networking, ssh, vnc, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I was wondering how I can access my Raspberry Pi outside my home network. I can VNC through a SSH tunnel over my WIFI internally but I could never manage to do it externally. Is it something to do with port forwarding and maybe DynamicDNS?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

On your home router you should check for port forwarding

There will be a table that has entries for host, port and some description.

to just get it done : 
1. check your IP address by looking at your router's WAN address.

2. on the router config/port forwarding, forward all requests to port 22 ssh to your RPI' IP address.
3. To test this just ssh to the address from step 1 , if its all working then you will get a prompt for username.

There are times when your WAN IP will change so yes if you want it to be permanent you should get a domain registered and then sign up for dynDNS service that will allow you to point your domain name to their DNS server and you will get a key from DYNDNS that allows you to run a script every 2-3 minutes to update YOUR actual WAN IP at DYNDNS so they can properly resolve your address when the ISP changes it.

I HIGHLY RECOMMEND YOU HARDEN YOUR RPI if you OPEN it up on PORT 22, install the BlockHost or any of these [Blocking IPs](http://archive09.linux.com/articles/48138)

Answer (score 0):

I recently read a good article on exactly what your looking for. You can find the article here:
http://lifehacker.com/5978098/turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-personal-vpn-for-secure-browsing-anywhere-you-go

Comment: While this article might answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I had already seen this page before but I was trying to do it the hard way and learn more.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `RaspBMC` for exemple, all external access are block by default.
You can change this :

Just edit this file :

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/secure-rmc
```

Found this lines :

```
logger -t iptables "Configuring ip tables for interface $IFACE"
if [ "$IFACE" != "lo" ]; then
    NETMASK=$(get_subnet $IFACE)
    iptables -A INPUT -s $NETMASK -i $IFACE -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i $IFACE -j DROP
fi
```

And add :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

just before :

```
iptables -A INPUT -i $IFACE -j DROP
```

Exit, save & reboot.
If you want to open all port => you can comment the logger line and all the if statment.
For an other port, just change the `22`